# How to write concatenation with Case statement for sql?

Tags: sql

My query is as below :

```
SET @MainSQL='SELECT   UserProfile.empfullname, UserProfile.UnitId, OrgaMaster.Extension as OrgaID,Payroll.UserID,Payroll.Year,Payroll.PayrollID,<br>
(Case Payroll.Month when '1' then '''January'''<br>
 when '2' then '''February'''<br>
 when '3' then '''March''' <br>
 when '4' then '''April''' <br>
 when '5' then '''May''' <br>
 when '6' then '''June''' <br>
 when '7' then '''July''' <br>
 when '8' then '''August'''<br>
 when '9' then '''September''' <br>
 when '10' then '''October''' <br>
 when '11' then '''November''' <br>
 when '12' then '''December''' <br>
 end)as Month
                FROM     Payroll INNER JOIN
               UserProfile ON Payroll.UserID = UserProfile.UserID inner JOIN
               OrgaMaster on UserProfile.UnitId = OrgaMaster.OrgaID Where OrgaMaster.Level=1'
```

Result still showing incorrect.How to write concate with case in sql

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: Data type for Payroll.Month column? Which dbms product? What's incorrect - i.e. what do you get and what do you want?

Comment: You need '' (double ') not ''' or ' - If the <br> tags are not part of a garbled post, remove them

Comment: Why not make a MonthNames table?

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT()` Function - ([LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh231515.aspx)) - Can parse the `CASE` statement for you and concatenate the result.

You should just be able to put your `CASE` statement inside the `CONCAT()` function.

I don't see that you have even tried to use `CONCAT()` though?

---